# Upgrade MongoDB Driver in Meteor 1.7.0.4

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

The default MongoDB driver version is 3.0.7 in Meteor 1.7.0.x

I need to use MongoDB driver version 3.1 since retryable writes has been fixed in 3.1 for multiple document updates (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1513)

How can I use driver version 3.1 with Meteor 1.7.0.x?

Comment: Did you try setting MongoDB version to 3.1.0 in package.js inside meteor packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The following is a workaround guide and should not be used in production apps!

Please not, that the last `mongodb` driver version, that is tagged as stable, is still `3.0.11` (2018/09). You should therefore assume, that MDG will not update the mongo driver until a newer version has been declared as stable.

Using any of the latest versions can lead to unknown / unexpected behavior, especially in production environments. Continue at your own risk.

#### Proceeding

- Create a `packages` folder in your project directory

```
$ cd ~/path/to/your-project
$ mkdir -p packages
```

- Clone or download [meteor from Github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor) (to `~/path/to/meteor`).
- Copy the core package from meteor to your packages folder

```
$ cd ~/path/to/meteor/packages/
$ cp -r npm-mongo ~/path/to/your-project/packages/
```

- Edit the file `package.js` to the following [latest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) release (currently 3.1.4):

```
// This has been moved out of the `mongo` package so it can be used by the tool
// via isopacket, without having to also load ddp-server.

Package.describe({
  summary: "Wrapper around the mongo npm package",
  version: "3.1.4",
  documentation: null
});

Npm.depends({
  mongodb: "3.1.4"
});

Package.onUse(function (api) {
  api.addFiles("wrapper.js", "server");
  api.export([
    "NpmModuleMongodb",
    "NpmModuleMongodbVersion",
  ], "server");
});
```

- Run your app, cross your fingers.

#### Alternative step

- Instead of downloading the whole Meteor project from source, you can just create a new folder named `npm-mongo` in `packages/` and the reproduce the files from [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/npm-mongo), then edit `package.js` according to the guide above.